# How to get sum of value from Json Array in Angular2(Typescript)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a Json Response

```
"carts": {
            "value": [
                {

                    "Amt": 40

                },
                {
                    "Amt": 20.25

                },
                {

                    "Amt": 10.30

                }

            ]
        }
```

I want to get the sum value of Amt field and the output should be 70.55
How to get this using Typescript.I am new to typescript.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 7):

I am very much in favor of the [Rxjs' Observable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833429/479251), but since no one else mentioned it : **Javascript arrays have a `reduce` function**, so one can use it in Typescript too !

```
// suppose variable carts already stores the deserialized json
let total: number = carts.value.reduce( 
  (a: number, b) => a + b.Amt, 0);
```

after @Stefan's comments :

Fixed mistakes &
better to not assign type  of b, so that it will be inferred from the context and maybe raise a Typescript error at compile-time.

Comment: That won't work this way since the items in `value` and thus your `b` and your initial value (your first `a`) are objects.

Comment: @Stefan You are right, and forgot the '0' initial value as well. Editing.

Comment: Just an additional note: I wouldn't type annotate `a` and `b` and let TypeScript infer the types. Otherwise for example if the objects in `value` don't contain any `Amt` values using `any` as type hides the resulting error.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I thought `any` was the actual "default" if nothing was indicated (and no type guards or like are used). (without the noImplicitAny option, which is the default)

Comment: In run time, if one of the Amt is not defined, I should get an "undefined" as a result of b.Amt, thus making the overall result NaN .

Comment: At assignments types are automatically inferred (e.g. `let x = 0;`). If a function definition contains the definition of the callback parameters, those are also automatically inferred (for example the relevant definition for `reduce` is `reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;`). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html contains useful information about that.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way of using JavaScript's [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function (which is also valid for TypeScript) would be:

```js
const response = {
  "carts": {
    "value": [
      {
        "Amt": 40
      },
      {
        "Amt": 20.25
      },
      {
        "Amt": 10.30
      }
    ]
  }
};

const total = response.carts.value.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.Amt, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Note that if you want to support IE8 you have to include a polyfill (like that on [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).

Answer (score 5):

You can use observable reduce.
If you have Http response then:

```
this.http.get('url')
    .map(response.carts.value)
    .map(res => res.Amt)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.carts.value.length; i++) {
        sum+= this.carts.value[i].Amt;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function like this:

```
public cartTotal(): number {

    let total: number = 0;

    this.carts.value.forEach((e:any) => {
        total = total + Number(e.Amt);
    });

    return total;
}
```

Comment: That won't work since `e` will be an object. Additionally if you want `e` to be a number it would be better to type annotate it as a number, not any. That way there would be at least a compiler error (which is one aspect why you use TypeScript) if you supply it with an object.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic way to do it.

```
  sum=0;
  for(let a of json.carts.value){
      sum=sum+a.Amt;
  }
```